# How to create a custom view that can accept another view as argument in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am struggling with creating a "generic" custom view in android.

What I want is a view that can accept some view when used in layout, and than position that passed view in it's own layout.

usage:

```xml
<SomeTag1/>
<com.example.MyCustomView>
    <!-- this subview is passed as "argument" and will be positioned within MyCustomView's layout later -->
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img" 
        android:src="@drawable/img" />
</com.example.MyCustomView>
<SomeTag2/>
```

my_view.xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:text="Title" />
    <!-- Here passed view will be positioned -->
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frame" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my attempt to retrieve view:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public final class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);

        //get passed view
        ViewGroup child = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0); //null
        ViewGroup child2 = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(1); //FrameLayout
        Object childChild = child.getChildAt(0); //null
        Object child2Child = child2.getChildAt(0); //null
        ViewGroup altChild = findViewById(R.id.view); //null
    }
}
```

I didn't managed to find right google query to find solution for this. ChatGPT also didn't helped me.
How can i retrerive passed view in MyView.java? Positioning it is not a problem, but i don't know how to get it from xml.